# What data does New Relic collect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

I consider using New Relic for profiling performance of a rails application. I know how useful New Relic is, but I worry about security. Concretely I want to know what data does New Relic collect and send it to their servers in default setting.

If you know about this question or any Web page, please tell me.
I knew this page, but too long, and I want to know more concretely for Rails application.

[Privacy Policy](http://newrelic.com/privacy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Relic has a good deal of documentation on security considerations with our Ruby agent:
https://newrelic.com/docs/subscriptions/security

One of the best ways to find out every single thing that the agent is sending to the data collection server is the audit logs in Ruby Agent version 3.5.5 and later: https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/audit-log